# Use normal application as Android launcher

Tags: java, android, android-launcher

I'd like to use a normal application I'm working on as the launcher because it's the only app that is running on the device. What do I have to add to my app?

Thanks,
Yannik

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. I like it, but it's bound to go awry.

Answer (score 2):

Use this intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: what's the problem? For more information, take a look at the **Home** application in **SDK Samples**